# Changing html content using javascript[Theory]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools

Suppose i open a website  say `stackoverflow.com` now it contains a lot of html content,texts,spans etc .How will i be able to change the content of html automatically using script(jquery) if i know the `classes` and `id` of the elements of html.

say a webpage has these elements

`<span class="a">Great</span>`
Now i want to change it when i open the webpage to 
`<span class="a">Not Great</span>` 
Since i have no control on servers or resources of files i can change it from `dev` but that is manually . how to do it automatically ?

Comment: You can't, there's a cross origin policy to make sure you don't mess with other peoples websites, but you could write a browser extension that does it for your browser only.

Comment: i wanna do that for my browser only! but how ? @adeneo

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: thats too long and i am in a hurry. can u give a quick code for my question? @adeneo

Comment: Can I give you quick code to build a browser extension! Really ?

Comment: C'mon everybody, you should all know about the joys of ***bookmarklets*** -- and that they're clearly what the asker is looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a ***Bookmarklet***.

A bookmark can be more than just a URL -- they can also be snippets of injectable JavaScript.

Bookmarklets can be used to alter or modify any page that you're viewing on the web. They can add additional information about the page, aide the user in reading it, or perform some automated action in a web app.

```
javascript:(function(){ 
  if (window.jQuery) alert("jQuery is present");
  else alert("jQuery is NOT present");
})();
```

Just create a new bookmark, and paste the above as its URL. Click the bookmarklet to execute it on any page (to see if jQuery is present).

You can also use the bookmarklet code as an `<a>` tag's `[href]` attribute -- then the link can be right-clicked and bookmarked from there (the easiest way to get a user to install your bookmarklet).

---

***My favorite bookmarklet is H5o, the HTML5 Document Outliner!*** 
 *Use it to check any web page's document outline structure, highly important for good SEO!*

- [**H5o Bookmarklet Installation Page**](http://o-o-o.ca/outliner.html)
- [H5o on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/h5o/)

Comment: and how do u initialize or un the bookmarklet on page load without manually clicking to it ?

Comment: All a bookmark needs to take action, is the user to click it! You could easily create a bookmark which also knows how to uninitialize itself (when clicked and it's already initialized).

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. You can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".a").text("Not Great");
});
```

Comment: You want to change stackoverflow html?

Comment: just an example only for my browser . since u can edit the html using dev tool but its done after the page is loaded and manually .  what i wanna do is create a script and just as when the page reloads i wana change the html ***for that time*** using `js script`

Comment: You can just put this code in a js file and set a link on current page `<script src="/path/to/yourfile.js"></script>`.

Comment: For basic changes, I tend to do this with the Developer Tools console (F12 in most browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Given your example...

```
jQuery(".a").text("Not Great");
```

Or, if you want to include tags:

```
jQuery(".a").html("<strong>Not Great</strong>");
```

Comment: You would put it between <script> tags.

Comment: You can't change it "automatically".